# For loop for Map giving me various errors

Tags: apex, error, map, for

I am unable to get a for loop for Maps working, I am new at this if you could, I would greatly appreciate it.

I am just trying to iterate the the Trigger.oldMap keys, and, everything I try gives me a different error:

> Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a
>   concrete SObject: Map at line 27 column 34

```
for( Map<Id, Quote__c> oldQuote :  Trigger.oldMap.getkeys() ) {
            if (oldQuote.quoteID__c == null) {
                sentQuoteIds.add(oldQuote.Id);            
            }
```

those are lines 25-27, I substitued these generic values and fields: to `Quote__c` and `oldQuote.QuoteID__c` from original custom objects and fields, but, I think the answer will be the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is my first question please forgive me if I my etiquette is off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method called `getkeys()` instead use `keyset()` to get all Ids

So you are using `Trigger.oldMap.keyset()` means it is `set<Id>` i.e. `Quote__c` ids

```
for( Id objId :  Trigger.oldMap.keyset() ) {
   if (Trigger.oldMap.get(objId).quoteID__c == null) {
      sentQuoteIds.add(oldQuote.Id);            
   }
}
```

So based key you can get object and there field values like `Trigger.oldMap.get(objId).quoteID__c`

---

Best way is just iterate over `Trigger.oldMap.values()` this will return list of `Quote__c`

```
for( Quote__c oldQuote:  Trigger.oldMap.Values() ) {
    if (oldQuote.quoteID__c == null) {
        sentQuoteIds.add(oldQuote.Id);            
    }
}
```

Let me know if this solved your issue or not.

More info check [doc Map_methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm%23apex_System_Map_methods)

Comment: Thank you for the very quick response, unfortunately, I can't get it working, I get : Error: Compile Error: Loop variable must be of type SObject at line 31 column 28. I tried both ways.  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkKogon Can you just update you code in your ques ? Are you using `Trigger.oldMap.Values()` or `Trigger.oldMap.keyset()` ?

Comment: I think I solved the issue, I think my problem was that I was going into a loop of Trigger.oldMap(Values), when I just needed to refer to the oldMap values while inside the Trigger.new loop.  Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: I somehow solved this before seeing your latest post a couple of minutes ago, but, I greatly appreciate the followup.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is no problem, except, this is my first day on this site, can you tell me what to do, I have to jump off the computer for a few minutes, I will look into how to do it when I get back. Thanks.